# Как узнать цвет интерфейса Windows 10 из меню "Персонализация". C#, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

Делаю WPF приложение на C#. Нужно узнать цвет, который в Windows 10 настраивается в меню "персонализация" и используется для некоторых элементов интерфейса. Огромная просьба привести именно кусочек кода, если получиться.

Comment: А как будет вести себя приложение например на Win7?

Comment: Это приложение задумывается именно под Win10 и особой важной функциональности не несёт, так что ничего страшного.

Comment: Ну тогда какой смысл в WPF? Ведь для Win10 есть UWP, который является прям аналогом WPF (с некими изменениями) и который поддерживает все "вкусности" Win10 (включая и цвет персонализации системы).

Comment: Если честно я и не знал что UWP всё это поддерживает. Попробую провернуть этот там, может быть там есть более очевидные решения.

Comment: Если проект разрабатывается исключительно по Win10, то ваш выбор как по мне должен быть исключительно в сторону UWP, ибо он под эту OS и разрабатывался. WPF хорош поддержкой "старого", но в нем вы не сделаете например Toast уведомления Win10 или ряд других наворотов этой OS без костылей. Решайте конечно сами, нужны вам эти костыли или нет... Если отвечать на ваш вопрос, то скорей всего реализация будет примерно [такой](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37775712/6808809), предположу, что еще в реестре это значение может быть, но где, без понятия...

Comment: А в UWP решение простое, там это на уровне [ресурсов](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/xaml-theme-resources#system-accent-color).

Comment: [Оно?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36392858/12888024)